# "sync is not defined" error showing in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

> sync is not defined" error showing in chrome extension while have used storage permission.please acknowledge me where is error and how
>   will solve message : "sync is not defined" stack : "ReferenceError:
>   sync is not defined↵    at eval (eval at 
>   (http://localhost:46950/app/popup.js:31:9), :1:1)↵    at
>   HTMLInputElement.
>   (http://localhost:46950/app/popup.js:31:9)↵    at
>   HTMLInputElement.dispatch
>   (http://localhost:46950/app/img/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:6:12417)↵    at
>   HTMLInputElement.q.handle

```
//manifest.json
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,     

  "name": "One-click ",
  "description": "This extension demonstrates a browser .",
  "version": "1.0",
   "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "popup.html"
    }

  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "popup.js", "img/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "css": [ "img/bootstrap.min.css"],
      "js": [ "app/popup.js", "img/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
    }
  ],
   "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "identity"
  ]
}

//popup.js
     chrome.storage.sync.set({ 'data':"helloset" }, function () {
            alert("saved");

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`*method* is not defined errors` usually means the method was being called while the library wasn't yet loaded or there's really no such method. In your case, I think it's the former. Looking at the [IzumiSy/manifest.json](https://gist.github.com/IzumiSy/765cfd6dc02c79de875e) sync example, you need to use `document.body.onload` first then call that function like:

```
// popup.js
document.body.onload = function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("data", function(items) {
    if (!chrome.runtime.error) {
      console.log(items);
      document.getElementById("data").innerText = items.data;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to save data locally you can use

```
document.body.onload = function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("data", function(items) {
    if (!chrome.runtime.error) {
      console.log(items);
      document.getElementById("data").innerText = items.data;
    }
  });
}

document.getElementById("set").onclick = function() {
  var d = document.getElementById("text").value;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ "data" : d }, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.error) {
      console.log("Runtime error.");
    }
  });
  window.close();
}
```